# Python2: pandas groupby get proportion of NaN in each group

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe with a group column and a values column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['CA', 'WA', 'CO', 'AZ', 'MA'] * 10,
                   'value': pd.Series(range(5) + [np.nan]).sample(50, replace=True)})
```

How can I use `groupby` on the group column to get the proportion of NaNs in the value column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do:

```
df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x.value.isnull().sum()/len(x))
```

The key here is to use the `.isnull` method of a Series object to get rows that `NaN` and then a simple proportion calculation to get your desired output.

```
group
AZ    0.3
CA    0.1
CO    0.1
MA    0.1
WA    0.1
dtype: float6
```

I hope this proves helpful.

Answer (score 1):

By using the difference of `size` and `count`

```
g=df.groupby('group').value
i=g.count()
j=g.size()
(j-i).div(j,0)
Out[489]: 
group
AZ    0.3
CA    0.1
CO    0.0
MA    0.2
WA    0.2
Name: value, dtype: float64
```